# GIT installation error for bash.exe

Tags: git

I have an issue in installing GIT for windows version 1.9

When I install that, during the installation, it errors that Moving file failed, code 2 (file bash.exe), and after the installation (after ignoring the error), when I check git install directory, I see no file called bash.exe, but there is one "Git Bash Here" in context menu. Can any one tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the result of an overzealous anti-virus (as in [this thread for another software](http://forum.greenheartgames.com/t/move-file-failed-code-2-during-installation/6174)).

You can check that by trying to simply unzip [`PortableGit-1.9.4-preview20140815.7z`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.4-preview20140815/PortableGit-1.9.4-preview20140815.7z) anywhere, and check if `bash.exe` is there or not.

Comment: Superb answer. Thanks a lot